# How to get the contents of the file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

i am trying to read the contents of my uploaded document in pdf and microsoft word but what is being returned is just some characters which are not human readable, can anyone assist me what is wrong

Here are my codes

```
$file = ReportAttachment::find($id);
if (File::isFile(public_path('report_attachments/'.$file->report_path))){
$path = public_path('report_attachments/'.$file->report_path);
$content = File::get($path);
dd($content);
return (new \Illuminate\Http\Response($file, 200))
->header('Content-Type',$file->mime);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are not gonna get results with `dd` it's only useful for debugging, it won't process anything like words in PDF

Comment: The dd was just for debugging but when i remove it tells me that the get function does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging i changed the storage from the public folder using the public_path to store the files using Local storage and here is the edited codes

```
if (File::isFile(storage_path('app/'.$file->report_path))){
$path = storage_path('app/'.$file->report_path);
$content = File::get($path);
$file = Storage::disk('local')->get($file->report_path);;
$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', $file->mime');
return $response;
}
```